# How many values is possible in enum datatype of mysql?

Tags: mysql

How many values could be used in enum datatype in mysql ?  I meant like emum('yes','no') ,here yes,no  are values ,how many of these could be possible with enum

Answer (score 1):

A quick lookup shows it's a max of 65535 elements. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/enum.html

> An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements.

as of MySQL 5.0 - 5.6

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html),

> An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements.

Answer (score 0):

An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements.

*Source*: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

```
An enumeration can have a maximum of 65,535 elements.
```

**[REFERENCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)**